# Como enviar datos de varias tablas usando sesiones en JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets

Tengo un problema cuando envío datos de una consulta a mysql con varias tablas, al enviarlas al servlet, el servlet queda en blanco.

Estoy utilizando *modelo - vista - controlador*

En la vista del proyecto tengo un formulario donde envio la petición
la pagina se llama movimientosCarga.jsp

***Formulario de envío de petición***

```
<form method="POST" action="movimientosCargaVerGuiasVuelosServlet.do">

    <table class="bg-primary">
            <tr>
                <th>Código</th>
                <th>Iata</th>
                <th>Número</th>
                <th>Fecha</th>
                <th>Estado</th>
                <th>Transito</th>
                <th>Ruta</th>
                <th>Acción</th>
            </tr>

            <%
     try {

        for(int i=0; i<vuelomovi.size(); i++)
           {   
               out.println("<tr>");
               out.println("<td><input type='text' size=1 name='txt_id_vuelo' class='form-control' value='"+vuelomovi.get(i).getIdVuelo()+"'></td>");
               out.println("<td><input type='text' size=10 class='form-control'value='"+vuelomovi.get(i).getIataVuelo()+"'></td>");
               out.println("<td><input type='text' size=10 class='form-control'value='"+vuelomovi.get(i).getNumeroVuelo()+"'></td>");
               out.println("<td><input type='text' class='form-control'value='"+vuelomovi.get(i).getFechaVuelo()+"'></td>");
               out.println("<td><input type='text' class='form-control'value='"+vuelomovi.get(i).getEstadoVuelo()+"'></td>");
               out.println("<td><input type='text' size=10 class='form-control'value='"+vuelomovi.get(i).getTipoTransitoVuelo()+"'></td>");
               //out.println("<td><input type='text' class='form-control'value='"+vuelomovi.get(i).getFechaCreacionVuelo()+"'></td>");
               out.println("<td><input type='text' class='form-control'value='"+vuelomovi.get(i).getRutaVuelo()+"'></td>");
               out.println("<td><button type='submit' formtarget='frame_vuelo' class='btn btn-success'>Ver Guias</button></td>");

           }
     }
     catch(java.lang.NullPointerException ex)

            {

                out.println("<tr>");
            }


        %> 
        </table>   

    </form>
```

En esta clase tengo la consulta sql:

```
package Dao
clase GuiasDao

    public class GuiasDao {
    ResultSet res;
    Statement st;
     public ResultSet buscarGuiasVuelosMovimientosCarga(Vuelo v)
    {
        try {
            Connection conn=ConexionMysqlCargomove_db.getInstance().getConnection();
            st=(Statement)conn.createStatement();
            String SQL="";

            SQL="select a.awb,r.ori_doc_rvas,r.des_doc__rvas,r.ori_vlo_rvas,t.piezas_tvas,t.kilos_tvas,t.volumen_tvas\n" +
                "from awb a,rvas r,tvas t, vlos v\n" +
                "where a.cod_seq_awb=r.awb_cod_seq_awb\n" +
                "and r.cod_seq_rvas=t.rvas_cod_seq_rvas\n" +
                "and v.seq_vlos=t.vlos_seq_vlos\n" +
                "and t.vlos_seq_vlos='"+v.getIdVuelo()+"';";

            res=st.executeQuery(SQL);

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GuiasDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex.getStackTrace());
        }
        return res;
    }

package controlador
clase MovimientosCargaVerGuiasVuelosServlet url patterns movimientosCargaVerGuiasVuelosServlet.do

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        Folio fo = new Folio();
        Vuelo vlo=new Vuelo();
        Reserva r=new Reserva();
        TramoReserva t=new TramoReserva();
        GuiasDao gdao= new GuiasDao();
        FoliosDao fDao = new FoliosDao();


        Connection conn = ConexionMysqlCargomove_db.getInstance().getConnection();
        vlo.setIdVuelo(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txt_id_vuelo")));
        ResultSet res=(ResultSet)gdao.buscarGuiasVuelosMovimientosCarga2(vlo);

        ArrayList<Reserva> reservamov = new ArrayList<Reserva>();
        ArrayList<TramoReserva> tramoReservamov = new ArrayList<TramoReserva>();
        ArrayList<Folio> foliomov = new ArrayList<Folio>();
        ArrayList<Vuelo> vuelo = new ArrayList<Vuelo>();

        if(res==null)
        {
            String error="No se encontraron datos";
            request.getSession().setAttribute("error", error);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("errorVerGuias.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }

        else
        {
            try
            {
                while(res.next())
                {

                    fo.setNumeroFolioCompleto(res.getString("AWB"));
                    r.setOrigenReserva(res.getString("ORI_DOC_RVAS"));
                    r.setDestinoReserva(res.getString("DES_DOC__RVAS"));
                    r.setOrigenVueloReserva(res.getString("ORI_VLO_RVAS"));
                    t.setTotalPiezasReserva(res.getInt("TOTAL_PZS_RVAS"));
                    t.setTotalKilosReserva(res.getDouble("TOTAL_KLS_RVAS"));
                    t.setTotalVolumenReserva(res.getDouble("TOTAL_VOL_RVAS"));
                    vlo.setIdVuelo(res.getInt("VLOS_SEQ_VLOS"));
                    foliomov.add(fo);
                    reservamov.add(r);
                    tramoReservamov.add(t);
                    vuelo.add(vlo);
                }
                request.getSession().setAttribute("foliomov", foliomov);
                request.getSession().setAttribute("reservamov", reservamov);
                request.getSession().setAttribute("tramoReservamov", tramoReservamov);
                request.getSession().setAttribute("vuelo", vuelo);
                request.getRequestDispatcher("movimientosCarga.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }
            catch(SQLException ex)
            {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MovimientosCargaVerGuiasVuelosServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Como se ve en el servlet por medio de colaboración de clases tomo los atributos de las clases Folio,Vuelo, Reserva y TramoReserva y le asigno el campo correspondiente de la consulta sql y después guardo los valores en ArrayList para enviarlos por sesion.

Después los recibo en la misma pagina JSP que se llama movimientosCarga.jsp

Aquí recibo los datos que vienen del servlet

```
<% ArrayList<Reserva> reservamov = (ArrayList<Reserva>)request.getSession().getAttribute("reservamov");%> 
<% ArrayList<Folio> foliomov = (ArrayList<Folio>)request.getSession().getAttribute("foliomov");%>
<% ArrayList<TramoReserva> tramoReservamov = (ArrayList<TramoReserva>)request.getSession().getAttribute("tramoReservamov");%>
<% ArrayList<Vuelo> vuelo = (ArrayList<Vuelo>)request.getSession().getAttribute("vuelo");%>
```

Acá el formulario donde se debería mostrar los datos

```
               <form method="POST" action="movimientosCargaVerGuiasVuelosServlet.do">
               <table>
                   <tr>

                       <th>Awb</th>
                       <th>Origen</th>
                       <th>Destino</th>
                       <th>Origen</th>
                       <th>Piezas</th>
                       <th>Kilos</th>
                       <th>Volumen</th>
                       <th>Id Vuelo</th>
                   </tr>

                            <% 


                                    try
                                        {
                                            for(int i=0; i<foliomov.size(); i++)
                                                   {
                                                       out.println("<tr>");
                                                       out.println("<td>"+foliomov.get(i).getNumeroFolioCompleto()+"</td>");
                                                   }
                                            for(int i=0; i<reservamov.size(); i++)
                                                    {
                                                        out.println("<td>"+reservamov.get(i).getOrigenReserva()+"</td>");
                                                        out.println("<td>"+reservamov.get(i).getDestinoReserva()+"</td>");
                                                        out.println("<td>"+reservamov.get(i).getOrigenVueloReserva()+"</td>");
                                                    }

                                             for(int i=0; i<tramoReservamov.size(); i++)
                                                            {
                                                                out.println("<td>"+tramoReservamov.get(i).getTotalPiezasReserva()+"</td>");
                                                                out.println("<td>"+tramoReservamov.get(i).getTotalKilosReserva()+"</td>");
                                                                out.println("<td>"+tramoReservamov.get(i).getTotalVolumenReserva()+"</td>");
                                                            }
                                             for(int i=0; i<vuelo.size(); i++)
                                                            {
                                                                out.println("<td>"+vuelo.get(i).getIdVuelo()+"</td>");
                                                            }

                                        }
                                    catch(java.lang.NullPointerException ex)
                                        {
                                                out.println("</tr>");
                                                out.close();
                                        }



                            %>    

               </table>
           </form>
```

Cuando intento consultar los datos el servlet queda en blanco

***imagenservlet***

[image: imagenservlet]

por favor si me pudieran ayudar se los agradecería.

saludos

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Primero analiza el programa por partes; por ejemplo confirma que obtienes datos de la consulta SQL (o incluso, pon unos datos fijos en los arrays para descartar errores de otras partes). También estaría bien que revisaras el log del servidor para comprobar si aparece información de errores.

Comment: gracias intentare y les cuento

Comment: gracias ya lo resolvi, era un problema en mis clases.